# Get the list of all annotations

Tags: chart.js

When hovering over the points, I'm trying to toggle one annotation's visibility (`display: true/false`).

I started by defining the `onHover` interaction

```html
options: {
  plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        one,
        two,
        three
      },
    },
  },
  onHover: (event, elements, chart) => {
    if (elements[0]) {
      // get the list of all annotations
    }
  }
},
```

Now, I'm stuck on getting the list of all defined annotations.

While browsing, I found [this issue](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/issues/221) about annotations. Assuming `myLine` corresponds to `chart`, I was expecting to get the first annotation with `chart.options.annotation.annotations[0]`. However, `chart.options.annotation` is not defined.

Am I missing anything here? Is it possible to programmatically get the list of denied annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are configuring your annotations in the `options.plugins.annotation` namespace so you also need to retrieve them from there instead of `options.annotation`.

So using this `onHover` will list your annotations:

```js
onHover: (event, elements, chart) => {
  console.log(chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Should `chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations[0]` return `one`?  I get `undefined`.

Comment: That is because it is not an array, you define it as an object so you need to target the specific annotaion `chart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations.one` in your example code

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. The annotation may also be referred as `hart.options.plugins.annotation.annotations['one']` which is easier if the annotation is referred in a variable/string.